# ReplaySubject replaying value only to the first subscriber

Tags: java, rx-java2

Is it possible in RxJava2 to create the `ReplaySubject` which emits the value only to the first subscriber, which subscribes **after** `onNext` is called?

Here is the example how is working now:

```
Subject<String> subject = ReplaySubject.create();
subject.onNext("hello");
subject.subscribe(System.out::println); // "hello"
subject.subscribe(System.out::println); // "hello"
```

And what I want to achieve is the following scenario:

```
Subject<String> subject = ReplaySubject.create();
subject.onNext("hello");
subject.subscribe(System.out::println); // "hello"
subject.subscribe(System.out::println); // nothing because "hello" have already been emitted
```

I'm assuming, I have to use some transformation between the `subject` and the `subscribe` method.

Comment: There is no standard component with this emission pattern. What should happen to the subsequent `onNext` calls: each subscriber receives them or it should be dispatched in a round-robin manner? If you want to prepend items to a particular flow, use `startWith(T item)`.

Comment: In my particular situation it is guaranteed that between each two subsequent `onNext` calls, someone will subscribe, so both strategies are perfect. 
In other words - the only constraint is: the last `onNext` is dispatched to the first subscriber, which subscribes after `onNext`.

Comment: You could try with `ReplaySubject.createWithSize(1)` and use `skip(1)` for the 2nd and so forth subscribers.